# Javascript create object without auto sort key

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var newArray = [];
newArray[3] = "Three"
newArray[1] = "One"
newArray[2] = "Two"
```

Result of this array is:

```
1: One
2: Two
3: Three
```

But I want to get result like this (sort by append):

```
3: Three
1: One
2: Two
```

Note: I don't want to lose the keys.

Comment: Show the JavaScript that you used as a [mcve]. The code you have so far means nothing because it doesn't even correctly represent correct syntax, so it's impossible to guess exactly how you got those pseudo-code results in the first place.

Comment: You can normally push the data sequentially into the array using push(), but if you want the data to be pushed sequentially and have the indexing different from the way you pushed it is not possible .

Answer (score 1):

you should push it sorted inside array, then it will print it in the order you added it.

```
newArray.push("Three")
newArray.push("One")
newArray.push("Two")
```

then you can do 1 thing key your assigning code, other then this array create one seprate array for only keys but that keys should be sorted in array like

```
keysArray.push(3)
keysArray.push(1)
keysArray.push(2)

keysArray.map(myKey=>{
  console.log(newArray[myKey])
})
```

Comment: But I want to use KEYs. I don't want to lose the keys.

Comment: please check updated solution